# IIS7.5 Debug vs Published permissions

Tags: iis, permissions, asp.net-4.0, application-pool

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 and IIS 7.5

My site accesses a specified servers hardware for some statistical analysis.

When I debug my site in Visual Studio, I can access other servers hardware information with now issue. When I publish the site to IIS running as ASP.Net 4.0 appPool because the site is written under the 4.0 framework, the hardware retrieval fails. (note: when I run the site and analyze the local machine hardware, it works perfectly... the problem lies in analyzing another machine on the network.)

My question is, What is the difference in permissions a site is running under when debugging in Visual Studio in comparison to a published site in IIS 7.5?

Things I've tried...

Changing the app pool identity to every possible built in option, and my own domain profile, which is local admin on the machine I'm trying to retrieve hardware info about.

Changing the user that access the file directory of the website.

Changing app pools period. (The site has to run under .net 4.0, or else it barks out bad things).

I'm thinking I may need to install the site directly on the server that's being analyzed, but I find it odd that I can get all the data from other machine when I'm debugging. Any insight someone could bring would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: NOTE: I can't go under anonymous access, and change the user ASP runs as, because I have to use .Net 4.0 framework, and impersonation. Unless anyone knows a way to run .Net 4.0 Asp (NOT Classic), impersonation, and windows authentication under IIS, and enable anonymous access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is, in some cases, you have to add the appPool identity running the site to the "Performance Monitoring" group for the local machine in order to allow an ASP.NET site access the server's local hardware resources...